# How do I negate a regex statement?

Tags: regex, ecmascript-6, regex-negation

I've been playing regex golf and identified a regex that encompassed all the words I was not supposed to match and none of the words I am supposed to match. The idea was that I could simply negate the regex and then get the opposite (encompassing all the words I am supposed to match and none of the others).

The regex I came up with `(\w)(\w)\2\1` matches anything with a pattern `abba`, so I thought using the negative lookaround `(?!(\w)(\w)\2\1)` would match me with anything not of the pattern `abba` however now it just highlights everything, here's the URL if you want to try it out: http://regex.alf.nu/4

Comment: If this is an option, use `grep -v`

Comment: Like `^(?!\w*(\w)(\w)\2\1).*`?

Comment: @InnocentBystander it's a web based interface so grep isn't allowed

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes that works! Can you explain why that works and what I tried does not?

Comment: `^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1)` in your site gives 193 points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you want to exclude matching strings that *contain* those repeating symbols. Thus, you need to add `\w*` (0 or more word chars) before the characters to test for repetition.

Use

```
^(?!\w*(\w)(\w)\2\1).*
    ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN0oN1/1).

So, the `(?!\w*(\w)(\w)\2\1)` lookahead peforms the following check right at the beginning of a string: if there are 0+ alphanumeric/underscore characters followed with 1 and 2 characters that are followed with the 2nd and then the 1st captured chars, no match is returned (the match is failed).

You do not need the `.*` part if you do not intend to match the text (i.e. if you just check if there is a match or not). However, if you want to exclude matching an empty string, just use `.+` instead of `.*` (`+` matches *1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern*).

Comment: Ahhh the anchor is necessary to exclude the empty string then yes?

Comment: No, to make sure the string is not empty, you can use `.+` at the end. You just did not precise what the expected behavior is for empty matches.